# How to thank god in sanskrit/hindi in Sanatan Dharm?

Tags: dharma-shastras

How to thank god in sanskrit/hindi in Sanatan Dharm? As christians use hallelujah, muslim use allahmudillah !!

Comment: Hindu's say "Jai Ho"  e.g. Jai Bholenath , Jai Devi , Jai Shree Ram etc. in hindi.

Comment: But these are like greetings when you meet someone. i need a special thank you GOD word

Comment: Yes ofcourse .  Devotees also use this to thank god after their whshes get's fulfilled.

Comment: Will saying Hariom Tatsat be fare?

Comment: `अनुगृहितोऽस्मि` is the equivalent to Thanks in Sanskrit.